# Unable to update database table using Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to update a column in a database table based on count however it keeps returning a value of 0 and not increment. When the user clicks the approve button then the line number should be updated using this method This is what I have so far.

```
public void SetRequisitionStatus0(List <string> reqNumbers, List <string> item_no)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandText = "requisition_sp_setstatus0";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@reqNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@item_no", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    //command.Parameters.Add("@ApprovedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@approve_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@line_num", SqlDbType.Int);

    using (command.Connection = connection)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            for (int i = 0; i < reqNumbers.Count; i++)
            {
                command.Parameters["@reqNumber"].Value = reqNumbers[i];
                command.Parameters["@item_no"].Value = item_no[i];
                command.Parameters["@line_num"].Value = i;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {
         throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to `Clear` the parameters on each iteration.

Comment: how would I do that

Comment: @TerriceBrown I don't know the problem is exactly, you should not comment out the `catch` block so you can see the exception. But one problem is definitely that you `Add()` @line_num in the loop. Why not just set its value like you do the others?

Comment: because I don't know how it would get the value

Comment: Did you write that code or are you maintaining it? If you wrote it then I don't understand how you don't know to do: `command.Parameters["@line_num"].Value = i;`

Comment: sorry that was a mistake on my part

Comment: @Crowcoder, it throws this exception 'An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@reqNumber' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.'

Comment: Please update your question with the current version of your code.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: What does `reqNumbers[i]` evaluate to? Is it ever null in any of the loop iterations? You can't have a null value input parameter without a default in the stored procedure. If null is the value you want then use `DBNull.Value`

Comment: no it is not null

Comment: it stores the list of requisition number and item number that was selected

Comment: That is the only explanation I can see from the code you have shown.

Comment: I'm no longer getting that error message. not sure why it was throwing that error and I didn't change anything. But my question is suppose the user approve a few items and the line number is updated; what if they go back and approve some more items on that reqNumber can it continue from the last line number used instead of starting over

Comment: can you assist me

Comment: Just so you know, you're probably wanting to do `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`